# Issue installing packages "labeling" and "scales" in RStudio 2022.02.3

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I usually plot my data with the following ggplot syntax:

```
ggplot(sent.TN.yr.avg, aes(y = (log10(mean)), x = YEAR, color = ECOREGION)) +
  geom_point(size = 1, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_smooth(se=TRUE) +
  xlab(expression(paste("Year"))) + ylab(expression(paste("Mean TN (", mu, "g", L^-1,")"))) +
  theme_light()
```

But this recently led me to the following `loadnamespace(name)` error:

`Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘labeling’`

I'm not sure how this code prompted an error related to "labeling." Still, I tried restarting RStudio and installing that, but it cannot be supported by this version of RStudio (2022.02.3). I also tried the same thing with the "scales" package and got the same result. I've also tried changing the repository to different CRAN mirrors with no success.

Any tips?

Comment: I doubt it is because of updating RStudio: largely doesn't interfere with packages. What ggplot2 version you're on? Also, `expression` is from `scales` iirc, install and load that too (with dependencies = TRUE).

Comment: I'm using version 3.3.6. RStudio is telling me it cannot support the package "scales" and the "labeling" package. I still don't know how "labeling" is relevant to my code, either.

Comment: 3.3.6? Hmm, there was never such a version. Either way, if it is in the 3.3s, your version of R is 5 years old or so. Reinstall R to the latest version (currently 4.2.1) and try again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how RStudio is saying it can’t support the packages? I agree with Phil’s suggestion, update your R. If you’re on Windows, this should help: https://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/

Comment: 3.3.6 is neither the version nr of RStudio nor of R itself, it's the version of ggplot2 and that's the most recent version. But I'm curiuous what version of R you are using?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ggplot 3.3.6 in response to Hashvardhan's question. I'm using the latest version of R 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Package ggplot2 imports package scales which imports package labeling. So in order to use ggplot you should have installed the other two packages as well.

The version of RStudio most likely has nothing to do with it. But if you  recently switched from R version 4.1.* to R4.2.* you have to upgrad all your installed packages (they have to be recompiled after a major R version release).

You can do this in RStudio: Tools -> Check for Package Updates...
or directly in R with: `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`

By the way, on the ggplot2 page there is an example of how mathematical expressions can be inserted into axis labels:
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/faq-axes.html?q=superscript#how-can-i-add-superscripts-and-subscripts-to-axis-labels

Comment: It's weird that the code is prompting the error with the package "labelling," I know. I don't know what's calling it, but it happens when I run this line of code only.